# Camel REST-DSL multiple query parameter passing with null values giving error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger, dsl

I have created Camel Rest-DSL in spring-boot project.Now at the time of swagger implementation, when I am passing the multiple query parameter with required and non-required fields, it's not capturing the null value at non-required fields.

My is sample code is something like that :

================
public class Router extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override 


public void configure() throws Exception,PredicateValidationException {

    JsonDataFormat json = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
    Exchange exchnage;

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        .apiContextPath("/api-docs")
        .contextPath("/swagger")
        .apiProperty("api.title", "Sample Services")
        .apiProperty("api.version", "v1");

        interceptFrom().to("log:received");

        rest().get("/getAppStatus?MainID={MainID}&MainID2={MainID2}&MainID3={MainID3}&MainID4={MainID4}").produces("application/json").param().name("Consumer").type(RestParamType.header).endParam()
            .param().name("UserRefId").type(RestParamType.header).endParam()
            .param().name("ConRefId").type(RestParamType.header).endParam()
            .param().name("MainID").type(RestParamType.query).endParam()
            .param().name("MainID2").type(RestParamType.query).required(false).endParam()
            .param().name("MainID3").type(RestParamType.query).required(false).endParam()
            .param().name("MainID4").type(RestParamType.query).required(false).endParam()
            .description("Get Application Status")
            .to("direct:getAppStatus");

        from("direct:getAppStatus").bean(idGen)
            .log("body before is : ${body}")
            .setHeader("operationName",constant("getAppStatus"))
            .process(new GetRequestProcessor())
            .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("{{route.ContentType}}"))
            .setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("{{route.getAppStatus}}"))
            .log("body after is : ${body}")
            .setHeader("opName",constant("getAppStatus"))
            .to("{{route.sampleURL}}")
            .process(new GetApplicationStatusResponseProcessor()).end();


}
```

}

====================
Here : 
UserRefId and ConRefId used as request validaters.

Query parameter MainID is required and MainID2,MainID3,MainID4 are fields that may contain null values.

Sample link :

Link1 = http://localhost:8080/swagger/getAppStatus?MainID=12345&MainID2=&MainID3=&MainID4=

But when it get triggered via swagger UI, in CURL it shows :

Link 2 = http://localhost:8080/swagger/getAppStatus?MainID2=%MainID2%7D&MainID3=%MainID3%7D&MainID4=%MainID4%7D&MainID=12345

Issue only persist when non-required field came into action.

Is there any parameter present that will allow the null values to be inserted as required format[Link1] rather like error link [Link2] ?

Comment: You cannot do this for query parameters in the rest-dsl with the `{xxx}` style, that is only for content-path. So just remove all of that after the `?` mark, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, Claus Ibsen,

I have only tried to remove "{}" from some query parameters and they were not working. Now as per your recommendation, I have removed all that  "{}" after "?"  and it's working  :)

Current link looks like  : 
http://localhost:8080/swagger/getAppStatus?12345&MainID2&MainID3&MainID4

where 12345 is "MainID" which is the required field.